# Unable to load settings file. It might be corrupted or contain invalid XML or contain duplicate identifiers

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to open my project Settings XMl

in order to add some configurable  pair to it

but I get this error:

```
Unable to load settings file.  It might be corrupted or contain invalid XML or contain duplicate identifiers.
```

However, my XML is very thin:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="Conduit.Mam.MaMDBEntityFramework.Properties" GeneratedClassAppName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting AppName="SavedSuccessfullyInDB" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">The Test saved in DB successfully</Value>
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

Comment: Have you got a stack trace for the exception that you can post?

Comment: it's an error in VS-2012 editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute for "SettingsFile" node should be "GeneratedClassName" not "GeneratedClassAppName".  Likewise the attribute "AppName" on "Setting" node should be "Name".

In my case I think the cause was Resharper being too aggressive refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this error ("Unable to load settings file. It might be corrupted or contain invalid XML or contain duplicate identifiers.") which was also the result of resharper refactoring.  After a little research, this was my solution:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Navigate to the projects `Properties` directory
3. Delete `Settings.settings` and `Settings.Designer.cs`
4. Start Visual Studio and open your project
5. Add a new Settings (Properties -> Settings)

The beauty about this approach is that Visual Studio will read your app/web.config and notice that you already have entries and will automatically add those key/values for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML declaration is using single quotes. I thought it needed to be double quotes. Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

This simple case sensitivity issue in my app.config caused the issue for me

```
  <setting Name="BlankPrescriberNoWhenWelshFormInGroup" serializeAs="String">
    <value>2</value>
  </setting>
```

this needed to be 'name' instead of 'Name'

```
  <setting name="BlankPrescriberNoWhenWelshFormInGroup" serializeAs="String">
    <value>2</value>
  </setting>
```

However note I've also had this before when I typed a capital 'S' for

```
<Setting name="value" serializeAs="String">
```

in my app.config rather than a lower case 's' as in

```
<setting name="value" serializeAs="String">
```

so case sensitivity can get you here watch out! And another to watch out for and uppercase 'V' for

```
<Value>2</Value>
```

when it really only likes 'v' for

```
<value>2</value>
```

Comment: I found and deleted the user.config file tucked away in AppData. For me the path was: C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\TestApp\TestApp.exe_Url_m5ounrdnbmxak2b1kdampbbaq1fx54wc\1.0.0.0\user.config.

I was then able to relaunch. I did indeed have a corrupted file - a bunch of NULL characters.